# Mapping torus of Klein bottle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This got 5 upvotes but no answers on MSE ([Mapping torus of Klein bottle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373435/mapping-torus-of-klein-bottle)), so I'm cross-posting to MO:

The mapping torus of a Klein bottle $ K $ is a compact flat 3 manifold.

The mapping class group of the Klein bottle $ K $ is the Klein four group $ C_2 \times C_2 $. See proposition 20 of [Paris - Mapping class groups of non-orientable surfaces for beginners](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1123).

There are exactly four compact flat non-orientable 3 manifolds, one of which is $ K \times S^1 $, the mapping torus of the trivial mapping class of $ K $.

Now for the four compact flat non orientable 3 manifolds. These are distinguished by their first homology $ H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}) $ (see Wolf)
$$
\mathbb{Z}^2 \times C_2, \mathbb{Z}^2, \mathbb{Z}\times C_2 \times C_2, \mathbb{Z} \times C_4.
$$
They correspond to the trivial mapping torus $ S^1 \times K $, the mapping torus of the Dehn twist, the mapping torus of the Y homeomorphism and the mapping torus of the Dehn twist plus Y homeomorphism, respectively.

See [the Wikipedia page for Seifert fibration with positive orbifold Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_fiber_space#Positive_orbifold_Euler_characteristic).

I'm curious how these homology groups are computed.

I understand the vote to close because I agree this isn't MO level. But it was asked on MSE two months ago with no answer so I feel like it is reasonable to cross post. I honestly won't be mad if you close this post. I just love MO and MSE and all the generous people here who have helped me learn so many interesting things!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sketch of an approach. What one needs to do is compute the induced action of the homeomorphism $f : K \to K$ on the generators of a presentation of the fundamental group of the Klein bottle $K$. One [can describe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/fundamental-group-of-mapping-torus) the fundamental group of the mapping torus of $f$ as $\pi_1(K) \rtimes_{f_*} \mathbb{Z}$, and once one knows the action of $f_{*}$ on generators, a presentation for the fundamental group of the mapping torus [follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160870/group-presentation-for-semidirect-products).

The first homology of the mapping torus is the Abelianization of $\pi_1$ by Hurwitz's theorem, and this can be computed from a presentation of the fundamental group by allowing letters in the relations to commute.

Comment: I appreciate this is a generically valid way to compute the first homology of a mapping torus but I was really hoping for some intuition specific to my question about why, maybe from a geometric perspective, we might expect these mappings, Dehn twist and Y homeomorphism etc, to have the particular torsion in the first homology that I list above. If no one wants to give an answer with any geometric content and just wants to give a generic algebraic topology recipe then that's ok and I'll just accept your answer in a few days.

Comment: Oh, sure. I think that doing out this approach should give one at least a starting point to finding an understanding of what is happening geometrically. E.g. it will produce loops generating the torsion, and one can draw them on a cube with identifications and think about what is happening. Will try to find time to think about this in the next few days, and write something down if I come to an understanding.